# Obtain author name and year with a single citation command with ieee style in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

I want to cite author name and year in my thesis using `\textcite` command. I can not do that since I am using IEEE style.

So please help me to turn "Mr Bla et al. [4]" to "Mr. Bla et al. (2018)" using `\textcite` or any other command in BibLaTeX

BibLaTeX command:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,sorting=nyvt,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=2,mincitenames=1]{biblatex}
```

Comment: I think that if you replace `style=ieee` by `bibstyle=ieee,citestyle=authoryear` you'll have what you want.

Comment: Do you still want to cite with numeric labels? Or should all citations be "Author (Year)"?

Comment: @moewe I want numeric as well as "author (year)" citations.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik It worked for \textcite but now I can not give numeric citations as well.

Comment: But why? How would you find the corresponding citation for say "Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998)" while all other citations are numeric? That is quite an inconsistent style and should be avoided.

Comment: @moewe Actually I just need the author-year citation to describe something is done by someone. e.g. As per reported by Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998) this thing is like this. But for other sentences, I need numeric citations. [2]

Comment: @AnantShirsath I completely agree with moewe. You should stick to one citations style. But if you insist you could combine `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear`...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik and Thank you for the word and I also completely agree with you both. But it's for my thesis so I don't think it is a big deal.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FWIW I think it makes little sense to use an author-year output in a document that has numeric citations otherwise. If for some reason you want to discuss the author or year of a work you cite do that explicitly in the text as in

```
In 1998 Sigfridsson and Ryde found that ...
```

or if you insist on using `biblatex` commands

```
In \citeyear{1998} \citeauthor{1998} found that ...
```

In those cases I would probably still add a proper reference to the work in numeric format with `\cite{sigfridsson}` so that it can be found more easily in the bibliography.

Mixing citation styles is often ill advised and can lead to confusion or at least irritation due to the inconsistency.

---

This is a copy of `authoryear.cbx`'s `\textcite` renamed to `\aytcite` so that we don't overwrite the old name.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, labeldateparts, sorting=nyvt, maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames=2, mincitenames=1]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\providebool{cbx:parens}

\newbibmacro*{citeyear}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{aytcite}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{%
          \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
          \printdelim{nonameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
        \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
          {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
          {}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit{%
       \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
       \printdelim{nameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
     \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
       {}%
     \usebibmacro{citeyear}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:shorthand}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:label}{%
  \iffieldundef{label}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{label}}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printlabeldateextra}}}

\newbibmacro*{aytcite:postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\bibcloseparen}
       {}}
    {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\setunit{\postnotedelim}}
       {\setunit{\extpostnotedelim\bibopenparen}}%
     \printfield{postnote}\bibcloseparen}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\aytcite}
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \iffirstcitekey
     {\setcounter{textcitetotal}{1}}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \textcitedelim}%
   \usebibmacro{aytcite}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}}
  {\usebibmacro{aytcite:postnote}}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson} or \aytcite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I completely agree with you on this topic but there are research papers who have used this kind of techniques just to be clear in what they want to convey. Anyhow, I am just gonna use it for my thesis, not for research publication so I don't think it is a big deal. And thank you very much for answering my question.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but the answer given here does not produce the expected results for me. Rather than printing `author (year)` it prints `author ("title")`. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: @BjarneThorsted On first glance the MWE works for me. I get *Author (year)* and the rest of the output looks OK too. There are no deprecation warnings or other relevant messages either. If the code doesn't work for you I suggest you ask a new question with MWE and make your complete `.log` and `.blg` file available.